# Android Leanback Keyboard Source

Tags: android-tv, leanback

Is the source code available for the  Android lean-back Keyboard?Basically the android box I am using shows its custom IME but I want to show leanback keyboard in place of that.

Comment: what box were you using? also did you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding Leanback Keyboard changed it's name, now it's LeanKey Keyboard, I've been lead to think this as searching Leanback Keyboard on the google play store only shows a few results with similar names. However the source code is available for it on GitHub here https://github.com/yuliskov/LeanKeyKeyboard if you were looking for the builtin android LeanbackIME keyboard that is provided by Android TV it is available on the Android Google source git here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LeanbackIME